# Muting a test in TeamCity across multiple projects

Tags: unit-testing, build, continuous-integration, teamcity, mute

We are using TeamCity 8.0.4 for our builds.

Our setup has a a set of "mirrored" projects that also contained "mirrored" build configurations (for Trunk/Release).

In scenarios where a test fails (in one of the Trunk builds, for example), i'd like to mute it and have that reflected immediately globally in all other projects.

Is this possible? If so, how is that done?

Answer (score 1):

In the Investigate/Mute dialogue, there is a Project Scope dropdown. You can select the Root project there and it will apply the muting to all projects.